# How to visualize frequency of category values along time per IDs in Pandas, Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, sequence, visualization

I have a Pandas DataFrame with IDs and categorical values (A, B, C) like this:

```
ID CAT
1  A
2  C
2  B
3  A
2  A
1  B
1  A
3  B
3  B
```

Actually, the rows represent a time sequence with records of categorical events by IDs, so there is a temporal dimension, but the actual datetimes don't matter, only the relative  sequence of events. Each IDs have identical number of sequential events in the whole DF.

I'd like to visualize the category value (event) sequences per users in a 2D matrix (like a heatmap) where rows represent IDs, columns represent time steps, and colored cells as the category values like this:

```
ABA
CBA
ABB
```

This is supposed to be a 3*3 matrix with colored tiles instead of letters. First row is ID 1 with it's three consecutive events, and so on. How is it feasible in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is a simple group by agg list. Which is basically, gonna display the unique id of an user with a list, that follows the given order of the elements.

So just

```
df.groupby('ID')['CAT'].agg(list)
```